# After Magento 2 Upgagrade products won't show in category's pages

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I upgraded Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.5 but i didn't upgrade ElasticSearch (it's on 7.9), now products are not showing in category's pages.
Is ElasticSearch the cause?
I checked the logs and there's no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ElasticSearch is the reason. You have to update the ElasticSearch version as per the below requirements stack:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Comment: I have the prod website (v2.4.0) in another Cpanel, i'm afraid that if i upgrade the ElsaticSearch the prod won't work. Can i have 2 versions of ElsaticSearch on the same server?

Comment: If you have 2 cpanel then you can assign separate ES server to each other. For more help contact to IT support.

Comment: You can create sub domain and ugrade ElasticSearch for that sub domain by connecting through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Update the ElasticSearch version as per the below requirements:https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

**or**

please run the command **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** and Check